# Two escape characters in a SQL query

Tags: sql-server, syntax, count, escaping, special-characters

So I have a bunch of strings in records that include the '/' character, eg:

```
RECORD_NAME
Foo bar
Foo/bar
Fo/o/bar
```

And several million records.

I'm wanting to say, count the number of records with 2 '/' characters.

So to look for one, I'd do, say:

```
select count(*) from my_table where record_name like '%[/]%'
```

Which would presumably get all the ones with one '/' in there.

**How do I go about counting the ones with say, two forward slashes?  Can you include regular expressions in a SQL query?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should work:

```
select count(*) from my_table where record_name like '%/%/%' and record_name not like '%/%/%/%'
```

This way you will always include the rows with two `//`, but if got three or more, the `not like` will avoid them

Comment: yup, will avoid all with three or more / :)

Answer (score 1):

Hard to determine exactly what you're trying to find, but if you're trying to distinguish rows that have 1, 2, or n `/` characters:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(y VARCHAR(32));

INSERT @x SELECT 'Foo bar0'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Foo/bar1'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Fo/o/bar2'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Fo/obar1'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Fo/o//bar3';

;WITH x(length) AS
(
  SELECT LEN(y) - LEN(REPLACE(y, '/', ''))
  FROM @x WHERE y LIKE '%[/]%'
)
SELECT length, [count] = COUNT(*) 
  FROM x GROUP BY length;
```

Results:

```
length  count
------  -----
1       2
2       1
3       1
```